# How to launch an EMR Cluster in AWS Data PipeLine only after completion of an activity in pipeline flow

Tags: amazon-data-pipeline

Is it possible to launch an EMR Cluster only after completion of one my activity in the AWS Data Pipeline flow.

1. Unload some data from Redshift (which might take an hour or hour+).
2. Start EMR Cluster
3. Execute a SPARK job in EMR cluster
4. Execute some other activity
5. Terminate the cluster

So, I want to have a dependency like "Start EMr Cluster" should depend on "unload data from Redshift to S3", and "Terminate Cluster" should depend on "Execute Spark job, Execute some other activity".

Can some one help me on this.

-Krish

Answer (score 0):

You can do it by utilizing `Precondition` 
Here is the docs for more details

Also you can do it by using copy operation and put copy operation as precondition

So you can put dependency as precondition once that satisfies then create EMR cluster.

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/datapipeline/latest/DeveloperGuide/dp-concepts-preconditions.html

[image: Precondition]

Comment: This makes activities to wait for precondition to satisfy, but that will not stop emr cluster launch. We dont want to launch emr cluster itself until some activity completes.